# Trying to select distinct values and have to format the date and sort as if its date time on MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server

So this is what I'm running:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
[Number1] as 'Number 1',
[Number2] as 'Number 2',
FORMAT([Date], 'M/d/yyy') as 'Date in full' 
FROM [DBTable1] as D1 
JOIN [DBTable2] as D2 on D2.Number2=D1.Number2 
JOIN [DBTable3] as D3 on D3.Number1=D2.Number1 
order by 'Date in full' Desc
```

I get :

```
|Number 1|Number 2|Date in full|
|123     |234     |9/30/2018   |
|345     |456     |9/6/2018    |
|567     |678     |10/2/2018   |
```

What I need to get:

```
|Number 1|Number 2|Date in full|
|567     |678     |10/2/2018   |
|123     |234     |9/30/2018   |
|345     |456     |9/6/2018    |
```

Basically, I need to get info from a few DB tables and have them in a certain format. The problem is having to sort by date while using the DISTINCT function and still having the date format in a certain way.

Comment: Do not order by your "formatted" value, but by the date field, i.e. `order by [Date] desc` and either add the original Date field in the select, or change the formatting by using [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I thought this would be possible but DISTINCT makes this not possible. "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." in other words, with DISTINCT you can only ORDER BY the names of the columns and not the column the data is recieved from

Comment: @Gerry You need to use group by and then order by. You can refer my answer.

Comment: The fact that you need to use distinct or group by without aggregates is almost always an indication that your query is logically flawed (or worse - your schema is flawed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to Group and then order.

Try this query.

```
SELECT [Number1] AS [Number 1]
       [Number2]  AS [Number 2]
       FORMAT([Date], 'M/d/yyy') AS [Date in Full]
FROM [DBTable1] as D1 
JOIN [DBTable2] as D2 on D2.Number2=D1.Number2 
JOIN [DBTable3] as D3 on D3.Number1=D2.Number1
GROUP BY [Number1], [Number2], [Date]
order by [Date] Desc
```

Comment: And remove the redundant DISTINCT

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Yes thanks. I updated the answer. Since we are using GROUP BY we don't need to use DISTINCT.

Comment: IT WORKED! thank you so much was struggling with this for ages. Had to remove DISTINCT at the beginning though

Comment: Hi, @Gerry if this or any answer has solved your question please consider voting and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita, Already upvoted it and have now accepted it as a solution. Thanks!